# Can't deploy container image to lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, dockerfile

I try to deploy container image to lambda function, but this error message appear

> The image manifest or layer media type for the source image <image_source> is not supported.

here is my Dockerfile, i believe i have use the proper setup

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

# Install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy function code
COPY app/* ./

# Set the CMD to your handler
CMD [ "lambda_function.lambda_handler" ]
```

Comment: Where exactly does this error occur?

Comment: When creating lambda function, after specifying the container image, A red box with the message appear @Marcin

Comment: @Bramanta take a look at [this official blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-container-image-support/) post which has an exact example of the python docker image packing, it worked for me.

Comment: What's in your `app/` folder?

Answer (score 22):

If you are using buildx >= 0.10 specifying target platform does not work since it also creates multi-platform index by default.

To fix this problem set `--provenance=false` to docker build.

For more details please see: https://github.com/docker/buildx/issues/1509#issuecomment-1378538197

Comment: Thanks! This fixed our issue. We use buildkit to build docker images for AWS Lambda hosted on AWS ECR. Our deployments started failing recently with error: 
"Resource handler returned message: "The image manifest or layer media type for the source image \***.dkr.ecr.\***.amazonaws.com/\***:\*** is not supported. 
 (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 400...)"

Answer (score 7):

Try by specifying the target platform of the image you build as `amd64`:

`docker build --platform linux/amd64 . -t my_image`.

I get the same error while trying to deploy a lambda based on an image that supports both `linux/amd64` and `linux/arm64/v8` (Apple Silicon) architectures.

Comment: Yes, ECR supports multi-arch images but lambda don't seem to handle them.